# Windows Batch script to rename files with it's folder name within a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a bunch of .flv files in subdirs and I need to loop through them and rename it according to its path.
I was able to loop through them all, but I don't know how to split the path and rename it using batch script. 
Here's what I have so far:

```
    echo off

    for /R %%F in (*.flv) do (

        echo %%~pF    
    )
```

The "echo %%~pF" prints the path for the current file on the loop, something like this:
\folder\morefolders\activity\ **NameThatIwant** \Videos\
I tried spliting with "delims=\" on my for loop but I get only "echo off".

I tried other tutorials, read other questions on SO but none of them were renaming the files from a split string from the path of the file in the loop.

Could you guys help giving suggestions or direct me to any material that explains those %% codes?

Thanks.

Comment: `for /?` will tell you everything you need to know about those.

Comment: Thanks @SomethingDark, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: If you found a solution, consider to post it as an answer and accept it; so the question does not remain open in the SO database...

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to split the path, though you could do it using for /f "delims=NameInthePath tokens=1", where NameInthePath - is some word in the path and tokens= gives you the first part of the path separated by delims.

Actially, if you need to rename file name you need to use REN command. If you need to change the path for the flv file - use copy of move command.

A batch file to rename all .LOG files to .TXT in the 'demo' folder and all sub-folders:

```
CD C:\demo\
For /R %%G in (*.LOG) do REN "%%G" "%~nG.TXT"
```

Comment: `"delims=NameInthePath"` ?? My best expectations would be some very surprising results.